# nested for loops to show output clearly segregated from input

Tags: c#

The following code using for loops prints five numbers entered by the user. I want the program to separate the output from the input by a string of dots.

```
using System;

class abc
{
    public static void Main(string[]args)        
    {
        int i, j;
        string[]tele = new string[5];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Five Numbers. Program Will Reproduce Them.");

        for(i=0; i<=4; i++)  // i is for accepting numbers
        {
            tele[i]  = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        for(j=0;j<=4;j++)  // j is for reproducing them
        {  
            Console.WriteLine(tele[j]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(".......................");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }     
 }
```

I have been trying to separate the input numbers from the output the program prints out with the string of dots: for this, code line `Console.WriteLine(".......................");` refers. In this position it puts the dotted line at the end after all the five numbers are reprinted. I did try to manipulate the program by shifting this code line before the j-loop began but that did not help. I am struggling to have a display like this shown below.

> Enter Five Numbers. Program Will Reproduce Them.
>   123
>   456
>   789
>   234
>   345
>   ....................
>   123
>   456
>   789
>   234
>   345

I request a brief clarification of the logic for putting the code line where it goes to produce desired output.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you should tag the question appropriately.

Comment: These for loops are not nested.

Comment: As a side note, I think iterating from `0` and using `<=` at the same time is usually confusing. Either start from `0` and use `<` (`for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`), or start from `1` and use `<=` (`for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)`).

Answer (score 3):

You just need to move the `Console.WriteLine()` statement. I'd recommend that in the future you step through your code with a debugger.

```
        for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)  // i is for accepting numbers 
        {
            tele[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(".......................");

        for (j = 0; j <= 4; j++)  // j is for reproducing them 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tele[j]);
        }
```

Comment: Will try to work with debugger. I wonder if it will throw up an error message because the code is running anyway: the dotted line appearing  at an unwanted location may not be detected as an error. May I request you to clarify the logic to me why this code line has worked in this place. I am an absolute beginner. My thanks for the correction.